# pandas: resample data by date and another group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['01/01/2000', 'aaa', 101, 102],
        ['01/02/2000', 'aaa', 201, 202],
        ['01/01/2000', 'bbb', 301, 302],
        ['01/02/2000', 'bbb', 401, 402],]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'id', 'val1', 'val2'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date').resample("M").last().reset_index()
```

this produces a single row:

```
    date        id  val1  val2
0   2000-01-31  bbb 401   402
```

What i want is last for each id.

```
    date        id  val1  val2
0   2000-01-31  aaa 201   202
1   2000-01-31  bbb 401   402
```

so i tried this:

```
df.groupby(['identifier','date']).resample(rule="M", on='date').last()

                            id  val1 val2
id  date        date            
aaa 2000-01-01  2000-01-31  aaa 101  102
    2000-01-02  2000-01-31  aaa 201  202
bbb 2000-01-01  2000-01-31  bbb 301  302
    2000-01-02  2000-01-31  bbb 401  402
```

I could probably extract the right data from this..but the function seems slow to begin with and it feels like there must be a better way - as this adds duplicate date index and other columns/rows that has to be further post-processed

any suggestions on better, more efficient ways of doing this

Answer (score 3):

Try `groupby()` and `resample()`

```
df.groupby('id',as_index=False).resample('M',on = 'date').last().reset_index(level=-1)
```

or `groupby()` with `pd.Grouper()`

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'date',freq = 'M'),'id']).last().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        date   id  val1  val2
0 2000-01-31  aaa   201   202
1 2000-01-31  bbb   401   402
```

Answer (score 2):

Since dates are always nice to pivot around the following solution might fit you well. Performance wise you would have to try out yourself.

```
df.pivot(index="date", columns=["id"],values=["val1","val2"]).resample("M").last().stack().reset_index()

#output
        date   id  val1  val2
0 2000-01-31  aaa   201   202
1 2000-01-31  bbb   401   402
```

Comment: thank u. this was a good solution, but rhug's seem to be a bit faster and i may not know the non indexed cols vs values.